# How do I display server side validation errors in Blazor (webassembly/wasm) using the ValidationSummary component?

Tags: blazor-client-side

For Blazor client side (webassembly/wasm), are there any good examples of how to display a server side error that occurs during submitting data to the server?

I would like to just display them in the ValidationSummary component.  What might the best approach for that?  Is there a sample of how to display the server side error, just like a client side error?

I am already trapping any errors and inspecting the ProblemDetails (or ValidationProblemsDetails).  But I have no idea how to "display" these issues in the ValidationSummary.

Comment: This posting does the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61662274/handling-api-validation-errors-in-blazor-webassembly

Answer (score 0):

There's a great article on how to do something like this:  https://blazor-university.com/forms/writing-custom-validation/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score -1):

You only get what the Server side API returns.  If it's your API get it to return an object containing the necessary information.

I use something like this:

```cs
    public class DbTaskResult
    {
        public string Message { get; set; } = "New Object Message";
        public MessageType Type { get; set; } = MessageType.None;
        public bool IsOK { get; set; } = true;
        public int NewID { get; set; } = 0;

        public static DbTaskResult OK(int id = 0)
            => new DbTaskResult() { IsOK = true, Type = MessageType.Success, NewID = id };

        public static DbTaskResult NotOK(int id = 0)
            => new DbTaskResult() { IsOK = false, Type = MessageType.Danger};
    }
```

As for displaying in Validation Summary, ???  That's geared for validation of individual fields.  The above object is coded to return information that can be quickly transformed into an Alert or Toast.

I've shown as example alert below - hides/shows and changes colour based on the alert type - slightly custom bootstrap alert.

[image]

Comment: Hi.  I clarified my question a bit more.

Comment: If you want to go down that route you will need to tie messages you get back to  a specific field (individual messages in the store are logged against a `FieldIdentifier`.) and then push them into the `ValidationMessageStore` on the relevant `EditContext`.  There's articles around on how to do custom validation that will probably give you enough information to do want you want to do.  There's one of mine here - https://shauncurtis.github.io/articles/ValidationFormState.html#a-simple-implementation.  Read, get started and then ask any more questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Personally, unless the errors are field specific and you want to display in the validation message against the specific field, I'd use an alert of some sort in the same place as the validationSummary, and turn it on and off as needed.  I've updated my answer to include an example of what I've done in an application.